# Como fazer row acompanhar altura das divs com d-block

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de um mosaico

```css
.row > div {border:10px solid white}
.B {background:blue; height:700px}
.G {background:green; height:350px}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid px-5">
    <div class="row d-block">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 float-left B"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 float-left G"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 float-left G"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 float-left G"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 float-left G"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Porém o `container-fluid` e nem a `row` acompanham o tamannho das divs que estão dentro eu tenho que definir o tamanho no css?

obs: ver em tela cheia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não acompanha pq vc usou a classe `float-left` nos filhos, para resolver isso vc tem que fazer um `clearfix` na `row`. Aqui na documentação do próprio Bootstrap tem isso descrito. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/clearfix/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o seu código, repare que eu coloquei uma borda na `row` para vc ver que agora ela respeita a altura dos filhos, pois agora tem a classe `clearfix`

```css
.row > div {border:10px solid white}
.B {background:blue; height:700px}
.G {background:green; height:350px}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid px-5">
    <div class="row d-block clearfix border">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 float-left B"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 float-left G"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 float-left G"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 float-left G"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 float-left G"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nossa, eu tinha esquecido completamente do clearfix e uso ele toda hora. Muito obrigado Hugo

Comment: @GiovanniDias acontece rss... Mas particularmente na que vc usa bs4 o Flex seria uma opção mais adequada. Mas com float sempre eh preciso um clearfix tanto que o próprio bs já tem essa classe pronta pra usar. Abs